# Left join with Pagerfanta Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'd like show results of two tables but I have this Exception: "Cannot count query which selects two FROM components, cannot make distinction".

My query is:

```
      $queryBuilder = $em->createQueryBuilder()
     ->select('e, e.id AS id, e.f14010101 AS f14010101, e.f14010105 AS f14010105')
     ->from('T140101Bundle\Entity\T140101', 'e')
     ->leftJoin('T140102Bundle\Entity\T140102', 'c', 'WITH', 'c.f14010201= e.id')
     ->groupBy('e.id');
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785143/doctrine-pagination-with-left-joins

Comment: Related discussion: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/pull/298. You may find relevant help by searching your error message plus the word "Doctrine". Have you done so already?

Comment: I added a potential answer to this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16658996/344517 (in case anybody ever stumbles across this)